# Shrink Ruby on Rails IF-ELSE code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

How can I shrink the following code.. Can it be done in one line instead?

```
<% if pos_count < 0 %>
  <% pos_name = "SHORT" %>
  <% else %>
  <% pos_name = "LONG" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be done in one line with the conditional operator (it's a ternary operator):

```
<% pos_name = (pos_count < 0) ? "SHORT" : "LONG" -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this view logic, and best practice is to minimize it. I would suggest extracting this out into a view helper (or decorator if you prefer).

As Istvan, suggested you can use the ternary operator, but for readability I would just leave it as if-else statement and move it into a method like so:

app/helpers/my_view_helper.rb

```
module MyViewHelper
  def pos_name(pos_count)
    if pos_count < 0
      "SHORT"
    else
      "LONG"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 on extracting the view logic into view helpers.
As the project grows, view presenters can also be used:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper?autoplay=true

Comment: That sound like good practice.. Can I then just call that method like this in the view: pos_count.pos_name ?

Comment: @Twiddr You would call it like `pos_name(pos_count)` from the view. I've updated the code above to reflect that.